# PHP 7 simpleXML fatal error

Tags: php, simplexml, shopware

I'm not able to solve a problem with simplexml.

I just set up an ec2 instance on aws linux/ubuntu with apache2 server and trying to install shopware.

Problem:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function XXX\Recovery\Install\simplexml_load_file() in /var/www/XXX/recovery/install/src/Requirements.php on line 104
```

Searching for known issues. I came up with manually installed packages for php. After checking phpinfo and php -m i asume that following modules are installed:

```
[PHP Modules]
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
dom
exif
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gd
gettext
hash
iconv
json
libxml
mbstring
mcrypt
mysqli
mysqlnd
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
Phar
posix
readline
Reflection
session
shmop
SimpleXML
sockets
SPL
standard
sysvmsg
sysvsem
sysvshm
tokenizer
wddx
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
xsl
Zend OPcache
zip
zlib
```

But I'm not sure if their enabled. Do I need to enable simplexml manually in my php.ini file? How to do this correctly?

version info:

```
PHP 7.0.12-1+deb.sury.org~xenial+1 (cli) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
with Zend OPcache v7.0.12-1+deb.sury.org~xenial+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies
```

Thanks for helping.

Comment: i was here from **centos**.  if it helps someone, use `sudo yum -y install php-xml`

Answer (score 6):

Solution:

I updated the missing package

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-xml
```

(I also installed some related xml librarys. There are plenty of posts on google related to this).

Afterwards this didn't solve my problem. The reason was I messed up my php installation. For any reason apache2 was configured with php5.6 so for me worked:

```
sudo a2dismod php5.6
sudo a2enmod php7.0
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Hope this saves somebody some time, in future.

Comment: I get E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.0-xml' when I try to install php7.0-xml I am using ondrej/php ppa with a scotch box using ubuntu 14

Answer (score 2):

No you cannot enable it in `php.ini`

You could check that it's enabled with `phpinfo` :

```
 <?php
     echo phpinfo();
  ?>
```

Or using command line :

```
php -i | grep -i simplexml
```

I would try to install it again as it should be enabled by default :

`sudo apt-get install php7.0-xml`

Comment: Thanks for help. Your answer helped me so much. I messed up installation of php5.6 & php7.

Comment: My pleasure @BenediktSchmeitz, thanks for sharing your solution